# SAS calculate age based on year of birth and a complete end date

Tags: sas, numeric

I have a data set that only gives year of birth. I want to calculate age based on when an individual was diagnosed with diabetes. For example I have a diagnosis date of 31Jan2002 and a year of birth 1964. The yrdob variable is NOT a date variable - it is only numeric and every time I try to make it a date variable so I can use the yrdif function it makes all of the years 1965 instead of recognizing the yrdob as a year, not the number of days after 1960.

Therefore my question is:

How do I take a numeric variable that is meant to be interpreted at face value (1965 means the year 1965 - not one thousand sixty-five) and make it a date variable so I can use the yrdif function to calculate age?

Comment: Make sure you may actually use YRDIF(); if you are working with e.g. GCP-related stuff, any imputations should be defined in the Statistical Analysis Plan or analogous document.

Comment: why not just do YEAR(diagnosis_date)-yrdob?

Comment: SAS isn't recognizing that yrdob is a SAS date, so when I try something like that it simply subtracts 1,965 days from the diagnosis date instead of recognizing 1965 is a year.

Comment: But the YEAR function just returns an integer representing the year, e.g. 2014.  Subtract 1965 from that and you get 49.

Comment: You are right! Tried your suggestion and that also results in the age, without having to calculate a date of birth first. Nice catch. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MDY function will make a date from numerics.  So for example,

```
datevar = mdy(1,1,yearvar);
```

will make a date variable for Jan 1, (year). (That's the default when only year is known).

So to get age difference, you can use

```
age=yrdif(diagdate,mdy(1,1,yearvar),'AGE');
```

Comment: `MDY` won't take zero for arguments 1 or 2. (I tried in SAS 9.2, might be dependent on version).

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, I feel like I've used 0 before.  Maybe that's DHMS (the datetime version).  Okay, provide 1 for both.

Comment: Thank you Joe, I would upvote you if I could, but I don't have enough rep. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 5):

Use the `MDY` function and make up values for month and day, e.g.:

```
date_yrdob = mdy(1,1,yrdob);
```

Which sets `date_yrdob` to 1st January of whichever year is represented in `yrdob`.

Comment: Thank you mjsqu. Would upvote, but I don't have the reputation to!

Comment: @user3306618 You can and should accept an answer as correct if it answered your question.